# App doesn't show database changes with SQLite Asset Helper

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm writing an app that comes packaged with an SQLite database.

I'm in the process of gradually adding to the database, but when I compile the code in Android Studio the app doesn't see the latest update to it.

The workaround I've found is changing the filename of the database and updating it in the code, but that's going to get very tiresome if I'm making frequent updates, and I feel there must be a better way.

For what it's worth, here's the relevant code snippet:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database5.db";
    private static final String BOOKS = "books";
    private static final String AUTHORS = "authors";

    public DatabaseHelper (Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // etc

}
```

Comment: just increment private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; with each build ( use may be build number ) and in onUpgrade right new alter/insert/delete queries

Answer (score 1):

You need to **increment** the version number then use the `setForcedUpgrade()`. Something like this:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);  

    // call this method to force a database overwrite every time the version number increments:
    //setForcedUpgrade();
}
```

You can found the details in the [sample project](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/tree/master/samples).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I include `setForcedUpgrade();` it gives me `Invalid method declaration; return type required`. Is there anything else I need to add?

Comment: That's strange. probably you have different class name with the constructor. Did you using the library from https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper?

Comment: I stupidly put it outside the constructor. But now it's within it and the database version is 2, but it's still not updating...

Answer (score 0):

> when I compile the code in Android Studio the app doesn't see the latest update to it

`SQLiteAssetHelper` only copies the database out of assets if the database does not already exist.

> I feel there must be a better way

If you are not modifying the database at runtime, and if you plan on distributing updates to that database in the form of fresh assets, you can use `setForcedUpgrade()`, as is covered in [the documentation](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper#upgrades-via-overwrite).

Otherwise, you can uninstall the app when you change the database, or clear the app's data in Settings when you change the database.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added `setForecedUpgrade()` but it's still not updating...

Comment: @Sebastian: Did you increase the `DATABASE_VERSION`? Also, what did you pass as the parameter to `setForcedUpgrade()` (if any)?

Comment: Yes, I increased the `DATABASE_VERSION` but I left the parameter blank. The only option I saw in the documentation was `You can additionally pass an argument that is the version number below which the upgrade will be forced`, which seemed unnecessary.

Comment: @Sebastian: Assuming your database versions are what you expect (the database one is lower than your `DATABASE_VERSION`), and you are calling `setForcedUpgrade()` in the `DatabaseHelper` constructor, then this should be working AFAIK. If you have not done so already, you might want to start from a clean slate: uninstall the app, run your app with `DATABASE_VERSION` set to 1, make a database change, then run your app with `DATABASE_VERSION` 2, and confirm that it is still not getting updated.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your sqlite database file name from asset folder
[here i have change name Quran.db to Quran1.db]

And from class where you have access it.
[from class also i have changed Quran.db to Quran1.db]

This method worked fine for me.

Comment: Please do no post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the answer. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?